# Counting number of times a value adheres to condition in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, where I would like count the number of times which an id occurs based on the condition that it falls within a certain category and in a certain period. I have a simple version of the dataframe here:

[image]

I would like to write a script which is able to count the number of times say, ID '1', occurs with category '1' during period 'period 1'

So the output would be something like:

count = 2

because ID 1 occurred in category 1 AND period 1, twice.

Please note that I do not want to explicitly name the ID in the script as I would like to count the occurrences of the other IDs, not just ID '1'.

Comment: Post your actual sample data in text form. Don't use image to show sample data.

Comment: I have edit my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61432082/6075699) check is it  expected output for your updated question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check conditions using [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas-dataframe-query) and then apply [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) func to find number of rows or count.

```py
len(df.query("id==1 & Category==1 & period=='period 1'"))
2
```

**Updates**:
For your later updated question answer would be

```
df.query("Category==1 & period=='peroid 1'")['id'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about where all the conditions are true, so `len` of the dataframe is the answer:

```
len(df[(df['ID'] == 1) & (df['category'] == 1) & (df['period'] == 'period 1')])
```

OR

```
(df['ID'].eq(1) & df['category'].eq(1) & df['period'].eq('period 1')).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas pivot function and in aggregate function mention count

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Category','period'], values='ID', aggfunc='count').reset_index()
```